# Homework help! Simple Python task

Tags: python, loops

Problem:

> For this part of the assignment, you will write a function to evaluate
>   the mathematical exponential function, ex. Your Python function will
>   be called badexp(x), because it really won't work very well, at least
>   for some values of x.
>
> Using the badexp formula: term[i+1] = term * x / (i + 1)
>
> For your badexp function, you will certainly need to write a loop, but
>   because of equation (7), you will not need to write a loop inside a
>   loop (a "doubly-nested loop").
>
> To write badexp, make a sum of the terms in the mathematical formula,
>   starting with i = 0. You can't keep going forever, so stop as soon as
>   adding a new term to the sum doesn't change the sum. That will
>   certainly happen eventually, because for large i the terms become very
>   small.

I could figure out how to write a better exp function, but this one is ridiculous and I cant figure out the loop. What I have so far:

```
def badexp(x):
    i = 0
    term1 = 1.
    term2 = x
    temp = term1
    while term1 != term2:
        term1 = temp
        term2 = 1 + term1 * x / (i + 1)
        temp = term2
        i = i + 1
    print term2
```

But that doesnt work :/

Comment: The "badexp formula" in the problem statement seems to treat `term` as a `list` and a `float`.

Comment: Why did you tag this "sse2", "minix" and "set-theory"? It involves none of these.

Comment: By the way, this isn't really that ridiculous. It's just the mathematical expansion of `e^x` as a Taylor series. It's terribly inefficient and numerically unstable, but it is a good lesson in why some theoretically-sound algorithms suck in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I see no need to keep track of two `term` variables. How about just

```
def badexp(x):
    i = 0
    acc = 0
    term = 1.
    while True:
        newacc = acc + term
        i += 1
        term = term * x / i
        if acc == newacc:
            return acc # numbers stopped changing
        acc = newacc
```

Comment: why did you assign 1 to term ?

Comment: The starting term is 1. After that you multiply the term by `x/(i+1)` for each `i`.

Comment: is it just traditional to start at 1? i can't see any mention of it in the problem.

Comment: @user2741333: You need to start at 1 to get a correct result.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition. There, you will see why the function works in theory.

Comment: hmm, i'll have to take your word for it, because that's much too esoteric for me to understand. foreign symbols, queer notations... in fact, all of this is a little taxing for my feeble mind. i think i'll go have a snooze now. maybe things will be more lucid when i wake. probably not. night, friend.